# Targeting child elements belonging to a specific class using JQuery :nth-child(n) selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to apply some CSS classes on a specific html button using JQuery. The button that I am trying to target is the 2nd button in the `#left-well` div. All the buttons in my html have the class of `.target` and I am using the `$(".target:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce")`. But upon running the script, the 2nd buttons of both the divs (`#left-well` and `#right-well`) get targeted.

How do I write the JQuery such that only the 2nd button in `#left-well` gets the class applied to it?

Here is the code for your reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".target:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>#left-well</h4>
      <div class="well" id="left-well">
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target1">#target1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target2">#target2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target3">#target3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>#right-well</h4>
      <div class="well" id="right-well">
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target4">#target4</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target5">#target5</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target6">#target6</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `#left-well` to selector like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left-well .target:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
  });
```

```css
.animated,.bounce{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Only change code above this line -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>#left-well</h4>
      <div class="well" id="left-well">
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target1">#target1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target2">#target2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target3">#target3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>#right-well</h4>
      <div class="well" id="right-well">
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target4">#target4</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target5">#target5</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target6">#target6</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next time please look the reference: [Jquery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: The reference was really useful. Thanks.